# Terraform Azure Cognitive Search RBAC API Access control

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-cognitive-search

Azure Cognitive Search currently supports RBAC authentication on searches as explained here :

1. The RBAC support which is in preview as of Aug 2022 needs to be enabled on the subscription.
2. Azure Search Instance -> Keys -> Enable support for both keys and RBAC

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-rbac?tabs=config-svc-portal%2Croles-portal%2Ctest-portal%2Ccustom-role-portal#enable-rbac-preview-for-data-plane-operations

However I could not find support for these API access control via terraform

[image]"

Question :
How can I terraform these controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search RBAC API Access control is currently in preview. Please ensure you are using the 2021-04-01-preview API version. You can find these controls under the DataPlaneAuthOptions section using "aadOrApiKey".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.search/searchservices?pivots=deployment-language-terraform

You can find the Azure Cognitive Search RBAC API documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-rbac?tabs=config-svc-rest%2Croles-portal%2Ctest-portal%2Ccustom-role-portal#enable-rbac-preview-for-data-plane-operations

Answer (score 0):

The hashicorp `azurerm` provider supports these properties on `azurerm_search_service` resources as of version 3.54, April 2023 ([changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v3.54.0/CHANGELOG.md)).

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/search_service.html#arguments-reference

The NOTE on `authentication_failure_mode` states

> authentication_failure_mode can only be configured when using local_authentication_enabled is set to true - which when set together specifies that both API Keys and AzureAD Authentication should be supported

So to enable both API keys and RBAC:

```
resource "azurerm_search_service" "<instance_name>" {
  name = "<name>"
  ...etc

  local_authentication_enabled = true
  authentication_failure_mode = "http403"
}
```